# Ios swift haneke EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, haneke

Sometimes I get this error with Haneke library and Swift.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

This doesn't happen every time I open the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version of the Haneke library fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

in Haneke/Cache.swift

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
```

+
with this:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
```

it should work fine then